# Exending Textbox to have a Unique Name

Tags: c#, asp.net

Is it possible to Exend Textbox to have a Unique Name ? I have tried using UniqueID poperty,but this is not accessible with Request.Form("UniqueID")

Comment: Why do you need to access it via Request.Form anyway? ASP.NET updates the Textbox control Text property with whatever it finds in Request.Form[ClientID] right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, all ASP.NET controls receive a unique ID and name (except for checkboxes and radio buttons which may have the same name, but different IDs).

If you gave your TextBox an ID, like so:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtFirstName" runat="server" />
```

Then you should be able to access it in code behind as a member of that name (txtFirstName).

If you want access through Request.Form, you can access it like so:

```
string textBoxValue = Request.Form[txtFirstName.ClientID]
```

Answer (score 0):

In ASP.NET any control you have will have a uniquie ID based on its assigned ID value.  You can only assign IDs via the .ID property. The .UniqueID and .ClientID properties are read-only properties that give you those corresponding values, but can not be modified directly.